# Node.js fs.writeFile: err returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I'm using 'fs' for writing into a file. The write process is going smoothly, and the file is created as I wanted, but the 'err' variable returns null. I presume this 'null' indicates no errors, but I wanted to be sure.

Is having 'null' from err in fs.writeLine function means there are no errors?

Comment: Yes, a null "err" object in async callbacks indicates no errors.

Comment: yep it means no errors

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is having 'null' from err in fs.writeFile function means there are no errors?

Yes.

The nodejs asynchronous calling convention that is used for nearly all the asynchronous callbacks in nodejs is to pass two parameters to the callback.  The first is the `err` value and, if it is `null` (or really any falsey value), then there is no error and the asynchronous result is in the second parameter (if there is a result value).

If `err` is not falsey, then it represents an error value.

This is often called the nodejs asynchronous calling convention and is used in a ton of nodejs functions.

Here's a reference article that explains/confirms this: [What are the error conventions?](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-are-the-error-conventions/).

Because `fs.writeFile()` only has an error/success condition and does not have any other result, the usual way to use `fs.writeFile()` is like this:

```
fs.writeFile('someFile', someData, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        // there was an error
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // data written successfully
        console.log("file written successfully");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll handle accordingly then :)

Comment: Added reference article.